# Making Bus Stop icon clickable on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Hello Guys is it possible to make Bus Station icon clickable using Google Maps API ?
I am currently working on an app but haven't worked with Google maps before. Can any of you please provide some tutorial links for this if possible
Thank You!

Comment: Have you looked at Places API? https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yes i have tried and no luck found @Verma